# Eclipse debug breaking on FileInputSteam.class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Recently my web app in Eclipse started breaking on a line in `FileInputStream.class` every time I run the app in debug mode. This happens as soon as I start the server. I have no idea what caused this to start happening, how can I fix it?

Comment: which line? What is exactly the issue? Are you sure that the source code that you use to debug really match with your Java version?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto line 106: `open(name);` and yea, im sure of that second bit